# Cannot install RealVNC viewer on RHEL 6

Tags: 64-bit, vnc, viewer, rhel6

I am trying to install RealVNC viewer on my RHEL6 server (kernel 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64). When I ran the RPM, I got the error

```
libICE.so.6 is needed by vnc-4.1.3-1.i386
libSM.so.6 is needed by vnc-4.1.3-1.i386
libX11.so.6 is needed by vnc-4.1.3-1.i386
libXext.so.6 is needed by vnc-4.1.3-1.i386
libXtst.so.6 is needed by vnc-4.1.3-1.i386
```

But these packages are already installed on my server. Is this error because the VNC viewer is for 32-bit systems while my server is 64-bit? If so, how can I get around this problem, as I can't find a free 64-bit version from RealVNC.

Thank you.

Regards,
Rayne

Answer (score 0):

RealVNC version 5.0 is now available and is fully support by Red Hat 6 and clones.